# Почему React не рендерит компонент с Routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Версия React 18.2.0

Проблема в том что реакт не рендерит мейн с этими роутами, без них все работает

Файл pakage.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux-first-history": "^5.1.1",
    "uniqid": "^5.4.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Компонент с Route:

```
import {Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Board from '../board/Board'
import TaskDetail from '../task-detail/TaskDetail'
import css from './Main.module.css'

const Main = (props) => {
    return (
        <main className={css.main}>
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path={'#'} component={<Board {...props}/>}/>
                    <Route path={'/tasks/:taskId'} component={<TaskDetail {...props}/>}/>
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </main>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

Компонент App:

```
import Header from './components/header/Header'
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer'
import Main from './components/main/Main'

function App() {
  return (
        <div className='wrapper'>
            <Header />
            <Main />
            <Footer />
        </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: если оставить только один роут `<Route path={'/tasks/:taskId'} component={<TaskDetail {...props}/>}/>` - ошибка продолжает показываться?

Comment: @Grundy, да, есть ещё несколько ошибок, все они связаны с роутами, например: react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Router> component:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправляем ошибку **"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')" in the v6 React Router**

1. Меняем импорт с **Router** на **BrowserRouter as Router**
2. Что бы наш роутер реагировал на нажатие Link меняем component на element для избегания ошибки **Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element**

Желательно, вынести  в index.js, что бы роутер был доступен во всем приложении. Иначе, как реализовано у вас, он будет доступен только внутри компонентов Main

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Board from '../board/Board';
import TaskDetail from '../task-detail/TaskDetail';
import css from './Main.module.css';

const Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <main>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={'/'} element={<Board {...props} />} />
          <Route path='/tasks/:taskId' element={<TaskDetail {...props}/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </main>
  )
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает